# Копирование значений одного массива в другой

Tags: java, массивы

Помогите исправить метод. Цель метода: скопировать в новый массив все значения, которые входят в диапазон.

Метод принимает заранее созданный массив, начало диапазона и конец диапазона, но возвращает метод массив заполненный только одним числом, которое входит в диапазон.
Теоретически это должно выглядеть так:

```
массив 1 = (34, 10, 56, 79, 0, 48)
```

пользователь ввел 40 и 80, результат:

```
2 массив = (56, 79, 48)
```

А практически выходит:

```
массив 1 = (34, 10, 56, 79, 0, 48)
```

пользователь ввел 40 и 80, результат:

```
2 массив = (48, 48, 48)
```

Код:

```
public int[] newArray(int[] array, int diaposonStarts, int diaposonEnds) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] > diaposonStarts - 1 && array[i] < diaposonEnds + 1) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    int finalArray[] = new int[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] > diaposonStarts - 1 && array[i] < diaposonEnds + 1) {
            int s = 0;
            s = array[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < finalArray.length; j++) {
                finalArray[j] = s;
            }
            System.out.println(s);
        } 
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(finalArray));
    return finalArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам не нужен второй вложенный цикл `for`

```java
for (int j = 0; j < finalArray.length; j++) {
```

```java
public static int[] newArray(int[] array, int diaposonStarts, int diaposonEnds) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] > diaposonStarts - 1 && array[i] < diaposonEnds + 1) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    int finalArray[] = new int[count];
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] > diaposonStarts - 1 && array[i] < diaposonEnds + 1) {
            finalArray[index] = array[i];
            index++;
        }
    }
    return finalArray;
}
```

Это то что касается Вашего кода.

---

Начиная с java 8 можно воспользоваться [stream api](https://habr.com/ru/company/luxoft/blog/270383/):

```java
public static int[] newArray(int[] array, int diaposonStarts, int diaposonEnds) {
    return IntStream
            .of(array)
            .filter(i -> i > diaposonStarts && i < diaposonEnds)
            .toArray();
}
```

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо!!!

Answer (score 1):

Все намного проще:

```
public Integer[] newArray(Integer[] array, int diaposonStarts, int diaposonEnds) {
    return Arrays.stream(array)
            .filter(e -> e>diaposonStarts && e<diaposonEnds)
            .toArray(Integer[]::new);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Первый for цикл оставляешь.

Потом создаешь новый массив, с длиной count - ты это сделал.

Потом делаешь count=0;

И копируешь первый цикл,  пишешь перед count++ finalArray[count] = array[i];